# Change color of multiple items based on the data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, custom-data-attribute

So there are three items the with attribute of `data-fill`, and each item has a span with a class of `.number`. Items should have black color if the value is less than than 20, and red otherwise. Any ideas how could I get them into some sort of a loop so it targets each item individually..?

```js
if($(".item").attr('data-fill') < 20) {
  $(".number").css("color", "black");
}
```

```css
.number {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" data-fill="19">
  <span class="number">20</span>
</div>

<div class="item" data-fill="40">
  <span class="number">40</span>
</div>

<div class="item" data-fill="30">
  <span class="number">30</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **iterate** over the elements and style corresponding element with `number` class.

```js
$(".item").each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('data-fill') < 20) {
    $(this).find(".number").css("color", "black");
  }
});
```

```css
.number {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" data-fill="19">
  <span class="number">20</span>
</div>

<div class="item" data-fill="40">
  <span class="number">40</span>
</div>

<div class="item" data-fill="30">
  <span class="number">30</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep several things in mind for this:

1. There are multiple `.item` elements so you need to loop over each of them and check for the value of `span` with class `number`
2. You need to find the `.number` element of the respective `.item` element so that you change the `color` of that `.number` element only.
3. Since it is a `data` attribute you can use `.data()` instead of `.attr()`:

```js
var elem = $(".item");
$(elem).each(function(){
  if($(this).data('fill') < 20){
    $(this).find(".number").css("color", "black");
  }
});
```

```css
.number {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" data-fill="19">
  <span class="number">19</span>
</div>

<div class="item" data-fill="40">
  <span class="number">40</span>
</div>

<div class="item" data-fill="30">
  <span class="number">30</span>
</div>

<div class="item" data-fill="12">
  <span class="number">12</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys for great answers

Comment: Yes I did from the @Nikhil since it was the first one, yours is equally good of course! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using filter():

```js
$('.item').filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('fill') < 20;
}).find('.number').css('color', 'black');
```

```css
.number {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" data-fill="19">
  <span class="number">20</span>
</div>

<div class="item" data-fill="40">
  <span class="number">40</span>
</div>

<div class="item" data-fill="30">
  <span class="number">30</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively it's possible to do this via CSS without JavaScript

```css
.number {
  color: red;
}

.item[data-fill^="1"]:not([data-fill="100"]) .number,
.item[data-fill="2"] .number,
.item[data-fill="3"] .number,
.item[data-fill="4"] .number,
.item[data-fill="5"] .number,
.item[data-fill="6"] .number,
.item[data-fill="7"] .number,
.item[data-fill="8"] .number,
.item[data-fill="9"] .number {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" data-fill="19">
  <span class="number">19</span>
</div>

<div class="item" data-fill="40">
  <span class="number">40</span>
</div>

<div class="item" data-fill="30">
  <span class="number">30</span>
</div>
```